# Add and remove class to jquery onscroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to add a 'fixed' class for [the header](http://www.inside-guides.co.uk/brentwood/hair-and-beauty.html) on scroll and remove it when it's scrolled back up in the following script, but not sure how best to do it:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var div = $('.header');
        var div2 = $('.headerPlaceholder');
        var start = $(div).offset().top;

        $.event.add(window, "scroll", function () {
            var p = $(window).scrollTop();
            $(div).css('position', ((p) > start) ? 'fixed' : 'static');
            $(div).css('top', ((p) > start) ? '0px' : '');
            $(div2).css('display', ((p) > start) ? 'block' : 'none');
        });

    });
</script>
```

This stop it triggering the event after each scroll down which is what happens now with the CSS specified in the script, hence I need to add a class.

CSS:

```
.fixed {
position: fixed;
}
```

Ideas appreciated.

Comment: You have gone full circles to my original idea of adding the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have translated your js to use css with the application of 1 class to the body

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var start = $('.header').offset().top;

    $.event.add(window, "scroll", function () {
        var p = $(window).scrollTop();
        if( p > start ) {
            $('body').addClass('fixed');
        } else {
            $('body').removeClass('fixed');
        }
    });
});
```

CSS

```
body.fixed .header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}
body.fixed .headerPlaceholder {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Use the answer I have now, I hope this is a test page you are using and not a page facing public

Comment: Updated display block for placeholder, should work properly now

Answer (score 1):

The add/remove class method works great.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
            $('.header').addClass("fixed");
        } else {
            $('.header').removeClass("fixed");
        }
    });
});
```

Here's a fiddle showing how it works: http://jsfiddle.net/gisheri/RpPEe/413/