# jQuery Offset - Add Class on Scroll to Div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to change logo color by adding class when it scrolls over div having light and dark background. So far it works well on 1st element, but not on others.

Here is my code which I got from Stack itself....

```
$(function() {

var logo = $('.mainImgLogo');
var hieghtThreshold = $(".light").offset().top;
var hieghtThreshold_end  = $(".light").offset().top + $(".light").height() ;

$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();


            if (scroll >= hieghtThreshold && scroll <=  hieghtThreshold_end ) {
                logo.addClass('whiteLogo');

            } else {
                logo.removeClass('whiteLogo');
            }

    });
```

});

```
        <h2 class="mainImgLogo">Page 1</h2>


<div class="pgs page1">
    Page 1
</div><!--page 1-->

<div class="pgs page2 light">
    Page 2  
</div><!--page 1-->


<div class="pgs page3">
    Page 3
</div><!--page 1-->


<div class="pgs page4 light">
    Page 4
</div><!--page 1-->


<div class="pgs page5">
    Page 5
</div><!--page 1-->




.pgs 
{
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    height:100vh;
    border-bottom:3px solid #333;
    background:#f3f3f3;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;


}
.mainImgLogo
{
    position:fixed;
    top:1%;
    left:0%;
    font-size:5rem;
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
    color:#333;
    z-index:99999 !important;
}
.light
{
    background:#333;
    color:#f3f3f3;
    text-align:center;
}
.whiteLogo
{
    color:#f3f3f3;
}
```

**whiteLogo** class is added/removed to **mainImgLogo** on 1st instance, but not on next one. Please guide me through...

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add and remove class to jquery onscroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22384670/add-and-remove-class-to-jquery-onscroll)

Comment: @Mohammad - this only adds class to other instance, but won't remove.

Comment: Hi the problem is repeating multiple class with same name (.light)
$(".light").offset().top; accessing always returns first element top value

Comment: @gowthamrajan - Yes - agreed - so what could be the best solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<style>
body {
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.pgs 
{
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    height:100vh;
    border-bottom:3px solid #333;
    background:#f3f3f3;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;


}
.mainImgLogo
{
    position:fixed;
    top:1%;
    left:0%;
    font-size:5rem;
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
    color:#333;
    z-index:99999 !important;
}
.light
{
    background:#333;
    color:#f3f3f3;
    text-align:center;
}
.whiteLogo
{
    color:#f3f3f3;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h2 class="mainImgLogo " data-scroll-group="header-group">Page 1</h2>


<div class="pgs page1" data-header-group="mainImgLogo">
    Page 1
</div><!--page 1-->

<div class="pgs page2 light" data-header-group="whiteLogo mainImgLogo">
    Page 2  
</div><!--page 1-->


<div class="pgs page3" data-header-group="mainImgLogo">
    Page 3
</div><!--page 1-->


<div class="pgs page4 light" data-header-group="whiteLogo mainImgLogo">
    Page 4
</div><!--page 1-->


<div class="pgs page5" data-header-group="mainImgLogo">
    Page 5
</div><!--page 1-->





<script>

$( document ).ready(function() {
    // This is a handy wrapper function that will return an array of matching element instead of a nodeList
function querySelectorArray(query, root){
  return Array.prototype.slice.call((root || document).querySelectorAll(query));
}

// Get all headers that are designated 'scroll-group'
var headers = querySelectorArray('[data-scroll-group]');

// Loop through the headers
headers.forEach(function(header){
  // Get the name of the group from the headers [data-scroll-group] attribute
  var group = header.getAttribute('data-scroll-group');
  // Get all the sections with a matching data-[data-scroll-group] attribute
  var sections = querySelectorArray('[data-' + group + ']');
  // Create an Event Listener for scrolling
  window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
    // Declare a lastSection variable that can store the last class that scrolled by
    var lastSection = false;
    sections.forEach(function(section){
      // Get the elements position compared to the viewport
      var offset = section.getBoundingClientRect();
      // If the position is smaller than 0 it has scrolled further than that section
      // The same is true for the scroll being smaller than the negative height - if so, it is out of view.
      if(offset.top < 0 && offset.top > -offset.height) lastSection = section.getAttribute('data-' + group + '');
    });
    // Apply the class to your header
    header.className = lastSection || 'mainImgLogo'; 
  })
});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```